# Как удалить медиафайл из БД Wordpress, но оставить сам физический файл?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть необходимость удалить миниатюру у поста (и все ее упоминания в БД), но не удалять физический файл (т.к. он может использоваться сразу в нескольких постах). Как мне это сделать? Функция wp_delete_attachment удаляет вместе с файлом, и на других постах, где эта же картинка используется - она становится битой. Текущий код такой:

```
// Удаляю медиафайл
$post = get_post( $post_id );
$attachments_del = get_children( array( 'post_type'=>'attachment', 'post_parent'=>$post_id ) );
if( $attachments_del ) {
foreach( $attachments_del as $attachment_del ) wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_del->ID );
}
// Удаляю миниатюру у поста
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_del->ID );
```

Есть идея каким-то образом блокировать на время действия функции wp_delete_attachment средствами PHP физическое удаление файла, но мне это видится диким костылем.

Comment: А в чём смысл сего извращения?

Comment: Одна и та же физическая картинка может использоваться как миниатюра сразу у нескольких постов. Данные в посте (в т.ч. миниатюры) обновляются циклически. Перед заливкой новой миниатюры, чтобы не засорять БД, удаляются все упоминания старой. Но если удалять и физический файл, то картинки в других постах становятся битыми.

Comment: Не бери дурного в голову (засорять).. . данные в базе ЗАМЕНЯЮТСЯ. И не ищи приключений на седалище изобретая всякую фигню

Comment: За 3 суток wp_postmeta и wp_posts раздулись до нескольких сотен тысяч записей. Время ответа сервера увеличилось в 3 раза. Не говорите о том, чего не знаете. А решение уже нашлось: подмена пути к файлу для удаления на несуществующий:

function filter_wp_delete_file( $file ) { 
$file = 'несуществующий путь к файлу';
return $file; 
};
add_filter( 'wp_delete_file', 'filter_wp_delete_file', 10, 1 );
// Мой код
remove_filter( 'wp_delete_file', 'filter_wp_delete_file', 10, 1 );

Comment: Если у тебя так криво работает, что раздувается и тормозит - дело явно не в ВП, а в  твои вот таких "решениях" Но ладно, чего мне таких умных лечить..